# Finding max element in 2D array in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

As we have support for Array to find max element using `maxElement()`, do we have any method using which we find max element in a 2D array `Array<Array<Double>>` in swift-2.0? Or do we need to write our own method?

Comment: If there is none, you could make an array that contains all the results for `maxElement()` for each "row" and then use `maxElement` on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any built in support for that but I suppose this is a simple enough solution

```
var matrix = [[3,5,4,6,7,],[9,2,6,8,3,5],[1,2,6,7,8,4]]

let max = matrix.maxElement({ (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.maxElement() < b.maxElement()
})?.maxElement()
```

max is `Optional(9)` in this case

or you can use map for the same

```
let max2 = matrix.map({ (a) -> Int in
    return a.maxElement()!
}).maxElement()!
```

shorter version

```
let max3 = matrix.map({ $0.maxElement()!}).maxElement()!
```

Comment: In the first case you call `maxElement` unpredicatable count of times and each time it iterates through all the array items. In the second and third case you iterate through all items twice wasting cpu resources and memory (because you don't apply any filters).

Answer (score 0):

```
    import UIKit

var val= [
    [2, 4, 9],
    [3, 6, 0],
    [8, 7]
]

func raiseLowerValue(inout val: [[Int]]) {
    for row in 0..<image.count {
        for col in 0..<image[row].count {
           if image[row][col] < 5 {
              image[row][col] = 5
           }
        }
    }
}
```

by substituting "if"  you can use by sort! or the other way.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimized and universal solution:

```
struct CustomObject {
  var date: Date
}
```

```
let objectComparator = { (p1: CustomObject, p2: CustomObject) in
            p1.date > p2.date
        }
        let result = params.compactMap {
            $0.max(by: objectComparator)
        }
            .max(by: objectComparator)
```

After `compactMap` you get a flatten array which consists of max elements from the nested arrays. Then you apply max for the second time.

This code uses as little memory and cpu as possible.